# How to sum the fields in a set of fields

Tags: javascript, html

I can't find the command that allows me to perform a simple sum:
in the Kw box I insert  data and the code  respond with + 3.7 rounding in excess.
Example of the calculation I need
4 kw
(4 + 3.7) = 7.7 I need it to respond by rounding 8 in the down box

thank you all very much

```
enter code here
  <fieldset>          
  <legend><strong>[kW]?  </strong></legend>
  <p>
  <input id="box1" type="text" name="power" oninput="calculate();" value=" Kw" /><br />
 </p>
 </fieldset>         
 <fieldset>          
 <legend><strong>sum 3.7</strong></legend>
 <p>
  <input id="result" type="text" name="power sum" value=" Kw" /><br />
 </p>
 </fieldset>
  <script>
  function calculate() {
    var myBox1 = document.getElementById('box1').value; 
          var result = document.getElementById('result'); 
    var myResult = myBox1 +3.7;
      document.getElementById('result').value = myResult;

   }
    </script>
```

Comment: Please add the code you've attempted to solve your problem to your question.

Comment: ok i did it, i entered the code, but it gives me a different result in the sum3.7 box, if i put 4 it should exit 8 (rounded)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've almost got it. You Just need to convert the text value from the input to a number, and then round it up.

(I've used placeholders in the inputs to remove the "Kw" text from the value)

```js
function calculate() {
  var myBox1 = document.getElementById('box1').value;
  var result = document.getElementById('result');
  var myResult = Math.round(Number(myBox1) + 3.7);
  document.getElementById('result').value = myResult;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend><strong>[kW]?</strong></legend>
  <p>
    <input id="box1" type="text" name="power" oninput="calculate();" value=""  placeholder="Kw" /><br />
  </p>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
  <legend><strong>sum 3.7</strong></legend>
  <p>
    <input id="result" type="text" name="power sum" value="" placeholder="Kw"/><br />
  </p>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0):

Each input doesn't have `" Kw"`, it should be numeric value.
So with javascript, you can sum this by:

```js
console.log(
parseInt(document.getElementsByName('power')[0].value) +  
parseInt(document.getElementsByName('power sum')[0].value)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `onChange()`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body >
<fieldset>
  <legend><strong>[kW]? </strong></legend>
  <p><input type="text" name="power"  onChange="sum(this.value)" />
    <br />
  </p>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
  <legend><strong>sum 3.7
    </strong></legend>
    <p>

   <input type="text" name="powersum" id="print" value='Change Text'>
    </p>
    <br />

</fieldset>
</body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function sum(value){
        console.log(value);
        value = Math.round( value + 3.7);
         document.getElementById("print").setAttribute("value" ,value); 

    }

</script>
```

Comment: Didnt you find my answer useful ?